# virt-manager - Change firmware AFTER installation

Tags: linux, kvm, virt-manager

`virt-manager` uses BIOS as the default option for firmware. There is an option to change this to UEFI just before installation, after the volume is set up.

[image: before]

However, after installation, the dropdown menu for changing the firmware disappears.

[image: after]

The installed system boots only with `UEFI` and not `BIOS`. The installation was a cumbersome procedure and I would like to avoid doing it all over again if possible.

Is there a way to convert the firmware to UEFI while keeping the contents of the system (disk) intact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found out that you can move the disk (the file with the `qcow2` extension) from one VM to another. So simply create another VM and add this disk. You can then do whatever you need to before the installation.

Comment: Can confirm, this works. I agree with @nomad's comment it seems a silly hurdle in a already complex process (Linux partitions are fine, but Windows just *has* to have a whole drive to get the GPT table on the ESP). With Virt-mgr selecting 'OVMF_CODE_4M.ms.fd', the secureboot efi option wasnt required by Win 10.

Answer (score 6):

You must edit your vm xml using virsh  and add in the `<os />` section
two items: `<flash />` (ro efi ) and `<nvram />` (rw environment).

You can read another preconfigured file for uefi in order to find more details about this two flags.

Comment: That leaves us with: `error: XML document failed to validate against schema: Unable to validate doc against /usr/share/libvirt/schemas/domain.rng`

Answer (score 4):

It seems you figured out your problem, but to answer: you can't do this via the UI because for an existing installed VM you can't usually switch from BIOS to UEFI and have things 'just work'. If you installed Fedora for example, the way boot is first configured is dependent on whether it was installed on BIOS or UEFI, so changing that setting at the VM level will likely mean the VM is unbootable.
If you want to change your firmware against the warning go ahead and change the starting `<os>` tag to `<os firmware="efi">`. It's that simple.

Comment: That does make sense, but it just seems silly in this case.

Comment: This must be added instead `<loader readonly="yes" type="pflash">/usr/share/edk2/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd</loader>` below <os>. See my comment on @Hamid's answer below.. the nvram line will be added automatically. ..given the triviality of this change, it could easily be done in the GUI of Virt-manager (maybe the nvram didnt automatically be added originally in VMgr, because it also copies a file from /usr/share/OVMF/ to /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/).

Comment: Also, this site (https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/discussions/3221#top) describes where to get the EFI file for Linux, at least for Debian: https://debian.pkgs.org/11/debian-main-arm64/ovmf_2020.11-2+deb11u1_all.deb.html

Comment: I have to modify my comment about just adding the loader line.. It looks like the "create new" method actually sets some variables inside the /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/win10_VARS.fd file. I was successful at using a copy of that file from a working VM, but not able to use the file generated after just adding the "loader" line. I was able to get it to load an Aioboot partition (grub-based), and tried Win recovery from ISO, and also CMD shell bootrec /bcdrepair. I got a "Verification failed:.." error initially and then after using diskpart and "bcdboot C:\Windows /s V: /f ALL" got "Failure.."

Comment: This link mentions the Diskpart and Bcdboot commands as well as how to create a new EFI partition that might work: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/windows-10-bootrec-rebuildbcd-and-scanos-say-0-windows-installations-detected.3661383/ ..oh, and on Ubuntu, the OVMF files are at: /usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS_4M.ms.fd (the ms files are symlinked to secboot files anyway, just fyi).

Answer (score 4):

I re-imported the `qcow2` image to fix the problem in (following [this](https://ostechnix.com/enable-uefi-support-for-kvm-virtual-machines-in-linux/) tutorial):

In Archlinux, I firstly installed:

```
sudo pacman -S edk2-ovmf
```

Then:

[image: Reconfigure]
[image: Edit]

Finally, the XML config file was changed from:

```
<os>
    <type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-q35-7.2">hvm</type>
    <boot dev="hd"/>
</os>
```

to:

```
<os>
    <type arch="x86_64" machine="q35">hvm</type>
    <loader readonly="yes" type="pflash">/usr/share/edk2/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd</loader>
    <boot dev="hd"/>
</os>
```

Comment: Can confirm that adding the single line `<loader readonly="yes" type="pflash">/usr/share/edk2/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd</loader>` to the XML file works. Line nvram line that also is created will be added automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your firmware against the warning of Cole go ahead and change the starting `<os>` tag to `<os firmware="efi">`. It's that simple.

Comment: This must be added instead `<loader readonly="yes" type="pflash">/usr/share/edk2/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd</loader>` below <os>. See my comment on @Hamid's answer below.. the nvram line will be added automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have enough reputation to comment, so I will just share my experience here.

I tried to do what @George Bungarzescu said, but the tags he presented are probably outdated. So instead I copied over the settings in a new machine that is initially configured to do UEFI. Result? Error during boot:
[image: Error]
I even copied over the new machine_VARS.fd for the old one. Did not work.

Just make a new VM as @nomad suggested, use the same qcow2 file and adjust your uefi settings accordingly.

Comment: this could be something to try, @WoodenThuds thanks for posting this;